# Unbolding Button Text in HTML Email Template

Tags: html, button, html-email, email-client

I'm currently trying to fill in for an engineer this week while he is OOO and I need to code a button to not have bold text.

Below is the code I'm messing around with:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center" style="padding:15px;" bgcolor="#000000">
    <a href="xxx" style="font-family:Helvetica Neue; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 1px; font-size:16px; color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;" target="_blank"><strong style="color:#FFFFFF;">LEARN&nbsp;MORE</strong></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I went to remove the "<strong , " and it's showing me that the string breaks.

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Sincerely,
Not a developer

Answer (score 0):

The strong tag is not only bolding the text but making it a white colour too. So, what you can do is use the span instead of strong, so that the white colour is still used.

i.e. change this:

```
<strong style="color:#FFFFFF;">LEARN&nbsp;MORE</strong>
```

To this:

```
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;">LEARN&nbsp;MORE</span>
```